# Вскрыть HTML из iframe стороннего сайта

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

Есть некая страница, которая доступна только владельцам аккаунтов. Причем для каждого пользователя контент на это странице уникален.
Главная проблема в том, что необходимо вытащить этот контент без дополнительных авторизаций. Недолго думая, я запихнул эту страницу в iframe и вывел у себя. Страница с уникальным контентом показывается, если пользователь авторизирован на сайте, где размещен этот контент. Но главная проблема в том, что если парсить эту страницу без кукисов этих пользователей, то, соответственно, никакого контента мы не получим, а если делать через iframe, как я и сделал, то исходный код страницы надо либо вручную пользователям вытягивать и вставлять в поле, которое я отведу для этого, либо посредством JS вытягивать.

И запоролся я на том, что не могу вытащить исходник.
Как можно обойти это ограничение? Есть какой-нибудь аналогичный способ это реализовать?

Comment: К счастью, это невозможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать противоречит политике безопасности браузеров: [Правилу ограничения домена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Чтобы обойти это ограничение, есть варианты, но все они предполагают либо владение вами обоими сайтами, либо надстройки над браузером: браузерные расширения, или обёртки типа Electron, где ваш код полностью контролирует браузерный компонент. Всё это потребует от пользователя устанавливать себе на компьютер что-то непонятное от вас. Мало, кто на это пойдёт.